# code blocks NSIS Error: Error launching installer

Tags: c, windows-8.1, codeblocks, nsis

I an trying to install code blocks on windows 8.1
i get this error at the beginning that :
 NSIS Error: Error launching installer
I've got the installation source from couple of sites but i still get this error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi @maktaf. This question is off topic for SO, consider asking for help on the super user exchange. (Though a quick google for your error throws up hundreds of related pages... I don't think you need expert help here...)

Comment: Your question could be on-topic if this error was Code Blocks-specific: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. " It is not, so you can expect more help on Super User indeed.

Comment: @MPI_What Thanks for ur information. I will ask other questions like this on super user exchange. My question might not need an expert but this is sth I've been searching so much and I didn't get any clear answer what to do, That's why i asked it here :)

Comment: @AndreaDusza Thanks, I will move my question there.

Answer (score 1):

This error is not CodeBlocks-specific, it can occur when trying to install any application on Windows. It makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow but I post an answer in case a future reader wants to ask the same question.

[This page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/nsis-error/4e2c6938-8727-4cc8-b783-557e5d0e9f26?auth=1) seems like the best available resource to help you, or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately the solutions on this site did not help to solve the problem, But thanks for Your answer :)